Running a GUI in a Singularity container over ssh -X
I'm trying to run gedit over ssh -X, so far, for the Singularity.def file I build (on mac in vagrant) with, I have
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:22.04

%post
    apt-get -y update
    apt-get -y install xauth gedit appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
    apt-get -y install locales
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
    apt-get -y install libxext6 libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6 libgtk-3-0
    apt-get -y install xvfb
    echo "export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/3422/bus" >> /etc/profile


%environment
    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8


Then when I copy it to the remote computer and try to run the container, I get errors (some directories were made and bound due to errors before),
singularity exec -B ~/gedit-save:/mnt -B ~/dconf:/run/user/3422/dconf -B ~/dbus:/run/user/3422/dbus gedit.sif xvfb-run -a gedit

** (gedit:3860309): WARNING **: 18:27:22.534: Unable to connect to dbus: Could not connect: No such file or directory

(gedit:3860309): dconf-WARNING **: 18:27:22.582: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: No such file or directory

(gedit:3860309): dconf-WARNING **: 18:27:22.589: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: No such file or directory

(gedit:3860309): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:27:22.745: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:3860309): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:27:22.745: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:3860309): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:27:22.745: g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

I am able to run other GUIs remote on this server, such as gnome system monitor, pyqt, or tkinter. Basically I'm trying to see if I can run GUIs that require sudo to install. Any ideas how?
